# when pacing order in checkout order is not confirming & showing spin and white screen

Tags: ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming, checkout

I have an ecommerce website , all website is working properly but when I am clicking on checkout button then order is not confirming and just a white screen appear and spinning , same issue with the contact form when I click on submit button it's not submitting and continuously spinning
kindly tell me how to resolve this issue

I have checked all the settings and I have removed all extra plugins just checkout is not placing the order just showing spinning and white screen

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.